# error: cannot find a symbol Java

Tags: java

tengo un problema.

Quiero recuperar el panel2 de esta programa para abrirlo en otro mediante:

```
public JPanel getPanel2()
{
    return panel2;
}
```

Para desplegar ese panel2 en el otro programa tengo esto:

```
if(e.getSource()== miCalcu)
            {
                panel.setVisible(false);
                panel= calcul.getPanel2();
                panel.setVisible(true);
                add(panel);
                setVisible(true);

            }
```

Pero necesito ese getPanel2 que no me reconoce.

Me sale el error ya antes mencionado. He usado esta misma función para otros programas y abrir estos, en otro clickeando en un `JMenuItem`, el resto, funcionan perfectamente con esa instrucción, recupero el panel2 sin problema y con la misma instrucción. Pero este me trajo este error. Aquí un fragmento del código(436 lineas en total). Si es necesario lo escribo todo.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.Panel;

public class Calculadora extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JTextField tfNumero = new JTextField(8);

    private JButton bSuma, bResta, bMultiplica, bDivide, bIgual, bClear, bPunto;
    private JButton b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9;
    private JButton bFactorial, bExpo, bRaiz, bCuadrado;
    private Panel panel1, panel2;

    private float n1, n2;
    private String operacion = "";
    private String strNumero = "";
    private int base;
    int sum,c;
    int x;
    String resSuma,resRes,resMul,resDiv,resExpo;

    public Calculadora()
    {
        super("Calculadora");

        panel1 = new Panel();
        panel2 = new Panel();
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,4));


        panel1.add(tfNumero);

        bClear = new JButton("clear");
        panel1.add(bClear);     


        b7 = new JButton("7");
        panel2.add(b7);

        b8 = new JButton("8");
        panel2.add(b8);

        b9 = new JButton("9");
        panel2.add(b9);

        bSuma = new JButton("+");
        panel2.add(bSuma);

        b4 = new JButton("4");
        panel2.add(b4);

        b5 = new JButton("5");
        panel2.add(b5);

        b6 = new JButton("6");
        panel2.add(b6);

        bResta = new JButton("-");
        panel2.add(bResta);

        b1 = new JButton("1");
        panel2.add(b1);

        b2 = new JButton("2");
        panel2.add(b2);

        b3 = new JButton("3");
        panel2.add(b3);

        bMultiplica = new JButton("x");
        panel2.add(bMultiplica);

        b0 = new JButton("0");
        panel2.add(b0);

        bPunto = new JButton(".");
        panel2.add(bPunto);

        bIgual = new JButton("=");
        panel2.add(bIgual);

        bDivide = new JButton("/");
        panel2.add(bDivide);

        bFactorial = new JButton("x!");
        panel2.add(bFactorial);

        bRaiz = new JButton("sqrt(x)");
        panel2.add(bRaiz);

        bCuadrado = new JButton("x^2");
        panel2.add(bCuadrado);

        bExpo = new JButton("y^x");
        panel2.add(bExpo);


        b0.addActionListener(this);
        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b4.addActionListener(this);
        b5.addActionListener(this);
        b6.addActionListener(this);
        b7.addActionListener(this);
        b8.addActionListener(this);
        b9.addActionListener(this);
        bClear.addActionListener(this);
        bSuma.addActionListener(this);
        bResta.addActionListener(this);
        bMultiplica.addActionListener(this);
        bDivide.addActionListener(this);
        bIgual.addActionListener(this);
        bPunto.addActionListener(this);
        bFactorial.addActionListener(this);
        bExpo.addActionListener(this);
        bRaiz.addActionListener(this);
        bCuadrado.addActionListener(this);


        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(panel1);
        add(panel2);
        setSize(350,220);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public JPanel getPanel2()
            {
                return panel2;
            }
```

Comment: El error que mencionas se trata de un [error de compilación](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=340:tipos-de-errores-en-programacion-de-compilacion-o-ejecucion-gestionados-y-no-gestionados-cu00242a&catid=36&Itemid=60), muy probablemente provocado por errores **de sintaxis** en tu código. Sólo para aclarar dudas, ¿estás agregando la llave final en tu clase `Calculadora` en tu código? (en el código que agregaste no aparece, de ser así, definitivamente ese podría ser el problema).

Comment: @C.Rodriguez Si, te digo, es una parte de todo el código.  Sin esa función getPanel2() el programa Compila sin ningún problema. Si es necesario, pongo el código completo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Saludos Acruzand.

El error que mencionas se trata de un [error de compilación](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=340:tipos-de-errores-en-programacion-de-compilacion-o-ejecucion-gestionados-y-no-gestionados-cu00242a&catid=36&Itemid=60), como te mencioné en el comentario.

Lo que pasa es que estás importando la clase `java.awt.Panel` y estás declarando `panel1` y `panel2` como ese tipo de `Panel`, sin embargo, en el `getPanel2` estás indicando que retorne un `javax.swing.JPanel`. Al ver los paquetes que importas, **únicamente** aparece `java.awt.Panel`, pero `javax.swing.JPanel` no aparece.

Estos son tus `import`:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.Panel;
```

Como ves, al final estás usando `java.awt.Panel`, deberías usar `javax.swing.JPanel`, para que te compile correctamente. Lo que debes hacer es quitar el `import` de `java.awt.Panel` y cambiarlo a `javax.swing.JPanel` y también cambiar todas las referencias en tus variables y en el constructor.

Variables:

```
private JPanel panel1, panel2;
```

Y en el constructor:

```
panel1 = new JPanel();
panel2 = new JPanel();
```

Comment: Gracias, pero a la hora de abrir ese programa de Calculadora en otro programa, no me muestra el JButton bClear ni el TextField tfNumero(el resto de botones si, y realizan su función normal. Si lo compilo normal si, sin problemas.

Comment: Según entiendo, en el otro programa estás tratando de obtener tu `panel2`, si ves tu código, los dos componentes que mencionas (el `JTextField tfNumero` y el `JButton bClear`) los estás agregando en el `panel1`, para que te aparezcan, deben estar agregados al mismo `panel2`